# How to configure VMs to automatically start when the host is on

Tags: vmware, esxi, vsphere, vmware-server

I'm using VMware esxi 5.1.

I have several virtual machines and need to power on them automatically when the host machine is powered on. I tried to go to the configuration tab from vSphere client and checked "allow virtual machines to start and stop automatically with the system", I also set the default startup delay and the order of the virtual machines to turn on, but this did not work. If I restart the host, nothing happens and I need to manually start the VMs. Strange thing is that in the Automatic Startup order all of my VMs have "Startup" "disabled".

I couldn't do anything with this, may be I need to somehow enable it?

How can vSphere be configured such that machines start automatically upon host start-up?

[image: VSphere screen-dump]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the settings window?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for uploading images. please see the image here: http://i43.tinypic.com/64mjjt.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are halfway there. On your screenshot all of your PCs are shown as "Manual Startup". You need to click the `Properties...` link at the upper right of this `Configuration` tab. From there you can configure your machines by moving them up in `Startup List` to the `Automatic Startup` section. This also lets you set the boot order for your machines. If you don't care about order you can move them in to the `Any Order` section.